Title: How to Connect CoPilot Usage Data in Office 365 Admin Center via API?
Description:
I'm looking for guidance on connecting CoPilot usage data within the Office 365 Admin Center using APIs to get data in real-time for Visualization purposes. I am using power bi. Could environment: azure.
Is it possible to retrieve CoPilot usage metrics through APIs provided by Microsoft Graph or any other method? If so, what steps or API endpoints should I use for authentication and data retrieval? Any insights or sample code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
I am currently exporting data from the admin center. Then utilizing the power platform.
